# Indexing Strapi Dynamic Zones with Meilisearch plugin

Tags: strapi, meilisearch

I have a Strapi content type called `portfolio`, which has this Dynamic Zone:

```
"body": {
    "type": "dynamiczone",
    "components": [
        …
        "body.content-block-list",
        …
    ],
    "required": true
}
```

The `body.content-block-list` itself has an attribute `blocks` which is a repeatable component of type `body.content-block`:

```
"blocks": {
    "type": "component",
    "repeatable": true,
    "component": "body.content-block"
},
```

`body.content-block` has an attribute `text`:

```
"text": {
    "type": "richtext",
    "required": true
},
```

In the Strapi Meilisearch plugin, I’ve defined an index for the portfolio content type that looks like this:

```
portfolio: {
    indexName: 'content',
    populateEntryRule: []
}
```

What should the `populateEntryRule` look like to index the `text` attributes of the `body.content-block`s in the `body.content-block-list`s in the dynamic zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the “JavaScript query” section of the [Rest API Documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/populating-fields.html#component-dynamic-zones), I’ve determined that the configuration I need is

```
portfolio: {
    indexName: 'content',
    populateEntryRule: {
        body: {
            populate: '*'
        }
    }
}
```